# Menu items always getting cleared

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with some fragments.
For example I have 2 fragments with different menu items.

Fragment A (menu)

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    manager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().getApplicationContext().SEARCH_SERVICE);
    sv = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    sv.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            pAdapter.filter(newText.toLowerCase());
            return true;
        }
    });


}
```

Fragment B (no menu , clear)

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

However when launching the menu items are gone. If I comment menu.clear(); menu items appears but all the fragments have the same menu items..

For those two fragments I call in onCreate setHasOptionsMenu(true);

How can I use different menu layouts with different fragments ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

with different menu in every fragment.